# CUPS server error when adding printer

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I’m new to Linux and installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo thinkpad. It was an work computer I was told I could keep.

I have a Canon imageclass mf445dw working on my local network.

In settings I see the printer listed automatically. I go to printer settings but cannot select it to be the default printer. I go to additional settings and it said no printers configured yet add. I click on add, it gives me options of generic cups-brf, enter uri, or network printer.

I select network printer > printer series with ip address > ipp network printer via dns-sd > forward

It looks for drivers, then asks to describe/name printer (which is already generated), I click apply and get: CUPS server error - there was an error during the CUPS operation: ‘server-error-internal-error’.

Not sure how to fix…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: Ok, I went to local host, and played around with the modify options until I could print a test page. Thanks